# JASidePanels Slide Menu iOS Native Library Crash only on device

Tags: iphone, xamarin, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I tried to use JASidePanel, but its crashes on device. I thought that is a problem in the link configuration, so, I changed it but the problem was not solved.

I flowed this example to create my project, but I using Xib file to create the login design screen: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Samples/tree/master/XPlatformMenus

I using:

- Xamarin.iOS: 10.3.1,
- Xcode: 8.2,
- MvvmCross: 4.4.0,
- MvvmCross.iOS.Support: 4.4.0
- MvvmCross.iOS.Support.JASidePanels: 4.4.0

The exception:

[The exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VpaVE.png)

Comment: Please report crashes and bugs in the MvvmCross repository.

Comment: Ok, I will report there.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a bug that has been reported on github